# Awk else-if statement seems to be executing twice

Tags: awk

I want to perform below tasks,

1) print word if word count of line = 1

2) print 4th word if word count of line > 3

3) print blank line in all other cases

Input file is,

```
cat file.txt
Hi there I welcome you
Hi there You
Hi
Hi there
Hi there I welcome you all
```

Expected Output is,

```
welcome

Hi

welcome
```

When I am using below code, it is giving me output with additional blank line, which is not expected.

```
cat file.txt | awk '{ if (NF>3) {print $4} else if (NF==1) {print $1} else {print "\n"} }'
welcome


Hi


welcome
```

I have resolved this by using below code,

```
cat file.txt | awk '{ if (NF>3) {print $4} else if (NF==1) {print $1} else {print $10000} }'
welcome

Hi

welcome
```

However I want to understand what went wrong and why else statement is being executed twice and giving me unexpected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `print` statement by default adds a newline at the end of the string it is printing. When used with `\n` it prints a double new-line as you see with the output. Use `printf` instead

```
awk '{ if (NF>3) {print $4} else if (NF==1) {print $1} else printf "\n" }' file
```

Without the explicit branch constructs, `if..else if..else`, you can just do

```
awk 'NF>3 { print $4; next } NF==1 { print $1; next } { printf "\n" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `print` command always adds a newline.  So `print "\n"` prints the newline you specified plus the one it added.

You can use `print ""` or `printf "\n"`.